# Is my daughter's avocado plant revivable?

Tags: leaves, avocado

My daughter was growing an avocado tree from a plant, and it was doing well. Unfortunately she got distracted while preparing for her school's testing period and forgot to take care of it properly for over two weeks. I'm not sure if the plant is able to be saved at this point, so I thought I'd ask all of you "green thumbs!"

It would be great if if it could be saved. It was pretty unique because it grew two stems instead of one! thought it was pretty neat. We've put it near sunlight in my office and watered it. The dried up leaves fell off. The top of one of the stems is darkened too.

Not sure if anything can be done at this point, but any suggestions or advice would be very welcome.

[image: Leafless avocado plant]

Comment: Suggest no more watering, just slightly damp until leaves form.